# Ubuntu 14.04 Asus G550JK SonicMaster External Subwoofer not working

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, asus, alsa

I have bought Asus G550JK laptop(G version of N550) and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I'm just a beginner in using Ubuntu, but I managed to make everything work fine except the external SonicMaster subwoofer. There is no 2.1 option in Sound Settings, I think Ubuntu doesn't see the subwoofer. I tried many solutions, but I only managed to enable 2.1 settings with subwoofer, but when I check the sound I can only hear some noises from the laptop, not the subwoofer.

I have added this at the end of the file:

> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
>
> options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4

but it doesn't change anything.

Also, adding

> [Mapping analog-surround-21]
>
> device-strings = surround40:%f
>
> channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,lfe
>
> paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker
>
> priority = 7
>
> direction = output

to the file:

> /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf

doesn't help.

Of course I changed the line in

> /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

to

> enable-lfe-remixing = yes

but all in all, it leads to nothing. I managed to enable 2.1 by adding the line:

> load-module module-combine channels=3 channel_map=front-left,front-right,lfe

to the file:

> /etc/pulse/default.pa

but, as I said, during the subwoofer check in Sound Settings I only heard some noises from the laptop.

Have you got any idea how to get it working? Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution to your problem!

- Install `alsa-tools-gui` (`sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui`)
- Start `hdajackretask` (either enter that in the terminal or find it in Unity)
- Select the codec: Realtek ALC668
- Check `Options` -> `Show unconnected pins`
- find Pin ID: `0x1a`
- check `Override` and select `Internal speaker (LFE)`
- press `Apply now`

If it works fine, select `Install boot override` and reboot.

Have fun with your subwoofer!

Comment: and with Asus N751JK. Thanks, amazing.

Comment: And with the N551JK as well.

Comment: This one doesn't work for my Asus N751JK and Ubuntu 16.04. Are there any differences between 14.04 and 16.04?

Answer (score 3):

Although the solution given by Mike works for many people, some models have different pins. If you're using ASUS N56JR you'll follow the following as [arch's documentations](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_N56jr) say:

Install alsa-tools-gui if you haven't already.

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Then open hdajackretask (you might have to open it with *sudo* privileges to make the changes take effect):

```
hdajackretask
```

- Select the codec: **Realtek ALC663**
- Check Options -> Show unconnected pins
- Find Pin ID: 0x16
- Check *Override* and select **Internal speaker (LFE)**
- Click on Apply now
- Open sound settings and change your sound mode to **Analog Surround 4.0 Output**

[image]

Test your subwoofer and if it worked, click on **install boot override** at *hdajackretask* and reboot your computer.

Comment: It works on my N56JR. "Apply now" printed an error so I directly did "install boot override", then rebooted and changed the sound settings. Thanks !