# ASUS G56JK no sound from subwoofer - UBUNTU 14.04 - Realtek ALC663

Tags: sound, asus

I just installed UBUNTU 14.04 on a brand new ASUS G56JK laptop and get no sound from the Subwoofer. The audio Chipset is Realtek ALC663.
I found some posts on the net and had various trials without success including hdajackretask with all possible combinations.
At the best, I obtain the 2.1 analog output with crystal clear sound coming from the laptop speakers but nothing from the subwoofer.
Any help welcome. Thanks.

Comment: It always helps to explain which solutions you already tried.

Comment: I followed the steps of http://askubuntu.com/questions/501989/ubuntu-14-04-asus-g550jk-sonicmaster-external-subwoofer-not-working?rq=1 - As the audio chip is different, I tried to override one by one all other unconnected pins related to internal speakers without success.