# Asus Sonicmaster subwoofer not working

Tags: sound, asus

The external subwoofer that came with my laptop doesn't work.

The laptop is [Asus N551VW-FY204D](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/N551VW/).

Installed OS is Ubuntu 16.04., all updated.

I did everything suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501989/ubuntu-14-04-asus-g550jk-sonicmaster-external-subwoofer-not-working), even played a bit with those pins, but the thing just doesn't work. Pins 16 and 1a are ones connected to the subwoofer, but any combo still gives no sound.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanls.

Comment: EDIT: it's an Asus problem, as it seemes. It also doesn't work on an exact same computer, but with Windows 10 installed.

Comment: EDIT2: apparently, for Windows 10, there is a driver, and now it works. Ubuntu - still nothing.